# Typescript declare class decorator and read it inside

Tags: typescript

`Hi,`
Im looking for a way to declasre a class in TS and read its value from inside the parent.

```
abstract class Base{
    readCollectionName(): string{
        // here return child class attribute value 
    }
}

@CollectionName('person')
class Child extends Base{
   name: string;
}

const c = new Child();
console.log(c.readCollectionName()) // person
```

Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
class Base {
  static staticName = 'base'

  getStaticName() {
    return (this.constructor as typeof Base).staticName
  }

  declare readonly prototypeName: string;
  getPrototypeName() {
    return this.prototypeName
  }
}

class Child extends Base {
  static staticName = 'child'
}
// @ts-ignore
Child.prototype.prototypeName = 'child'

console.log(
  new Child().getStaticName(),
  new Child().getPrototypeName()
)
```

Decorator basically should create a hidden static or prototype property which can be read from base